# jQueryMobile - open a popup programmatically fails with js error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Opening a jQuery Mobile popup programmatically results in a javascript runtime error.

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'nodeName' of undefined or null reference

I've tested with both IE and Chrome, which have similar results.

```
<div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="c" data-dissmissible="false" class="ui-corner-all">
    <div data-role="header"><h1></h1></div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all ui-content">
        <p id="myPopupText">test test</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#main").on("pageinit", function () {
        $("#myPopup").popup("open", { transition: "slideup" });
    });
</script>
```

I've also tried with .popup() before .popup("open"). Debugging in VS2015 I see that the popup is displayed, but while running it disappears again when the exception is fired.

What's causing this exception, and how may I fix it?

Comment: Which file is the error coming from?

Comment: jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to open the popup just the first time the page is loaded?  if so use $(document).on(... and try a slight delay:

```
$(document).on("pageinit","#main", function(){ 
   setTimeout(function(){
      $("#myPopup").popup("open", { transition: "slideup"   });
    }, 10);   
});
```

Do you want it to popup each time the page is visited.? Use the pagecontainer widget [transition event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-transition):

```
$(document).on( "pagecontainertransition", function( event, ui ) { 
    if (ui.toPage.prop("id") == "main"){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $("#myPopup").popup("open", { transition: "flip"   });
      }, 10); 
    }   
});
```

Do you want to launch the popup after the page has loaded in response to a user action?

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#main", function(){ 
  $("#btnPop").on("click", function(){
    $("#myPopup").popup("open", { transition: "flip"   });
  });
});
```

## **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/xOXNww)**

Comment: I still get the javascript exception when calling the .popup method.

Unhandled exception at line 7, column 5548 in ..../jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'nodeName' of undefined or null reference

Comment: @Kman, does the codepen give you the error? How and where are you adding jQuery and jQuery Mobile scripts/CSS? Are you using any other libraries that might conflict?

Comment: No, only while running in VS2015. I've also disabled other libraries, but it doesn't help. This is only an issue running in debug mode, besides that your code is running fine.